# PHP doesn't fill in session files

Tags: php, apache, session

I came across with a strange problem today. I swept all the questions here but none of them resolved my issue.

When I start a session with `session_start()`, a session file with format `sess_xxxxxxxx` is created but the session variables is not written in the file.

To make sure I did some tests, couldn't find any problem. For example the following code

```
<?php

$path = '/var/lib/php5/sess_aq2ctf49sa0jtplbaqqanqogt3';
foreach( array('file_exists', 'is_dir', 'is_readable', 'is_writeable') as $fn ) {
  $rc = $fn($path);
  echo $fn, ': ', $rc ? 'true' : 'false', "<br />\n";
}
```

prints

```
file_exists: true
is_dir: false
is_readable: true
is_writeable: true
```

so I see no problem of file permissions. However, if I run a very simple script as follows

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = "Session test";
  echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

I only get empty session files

```
drwx-wx-wt  2 www-data www-data  40K Dec  9 04:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 root     root     4.0K Dec  8 05:09 ..
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data    0 Dec  9 04:28 sess_4cfr69tfe3euujr70p4vuj95v7
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data    0 Dec  9 04:23 sess_aq2ctf49sa0jtplbaqqanqogt3
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data    0 Dec  9 04:27 sess_bk89n2qomkp0cmm0r901i4dqm5
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data    0 Dec  9 04:26 sess_h4vsd0nn7mpbbl539f590f0n16
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data    0 Dec  9 04:26 sess_na6cgdimp4t3sk1pu86rcu4e75
```

You can see all settings related to session in php.ini below

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Any help will be appreciated much. Thanks

Comment: how is the session config in php.ini? please post the session configs

Comment: @donald123 I added now.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make the directory the owner of your webserver.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/lib/php5
```

Comment: This should be a comment. [answer]

Comment: You need to have 50 reputation to comment. I don't have that much!